# python - igraph plot not available (cairo already installed)

Tags: python, plot, igraph

I've installed py2cairo using brew, but keep getting errors when trying to plot with igraph. I get the following error:

```
>>> import igraph as ig
>>> from igraph import *
>>> UG = ig.Graph()
>>> UG.add_vertex('a')
>>> UG.add_vertex('b')
>>> UG.add_vertex('c')
>>> UG.add_vertex('d')
>>> UG.add_edge('a','d')
>>> UG.add_edge('a','c')
>>> UG.add_edge('b','c')
>>> UG.add_edge('b','a')

>>> layout = UG.layout_kamada_kawai()
>>> plot(UG,layout = layout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 427, in plot
    result = Plot(target, bbox, background="white")
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 122, in __init__
    self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
  File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__
    raise TypeError("plotting not available")
TypeError: plotting not available
```

Answer (score 2):

`brew` probably installs `py2cairo` for its own Python, while you are running igraph under Anaconda Python. A module installed for one Python distribution on your machine will not appear magically under the other Python distribution, so you'll either have to get `py2cairo` for Anaconda Python or compile the Python interface of igraph for Homebrew's Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I searched for py2cairo installation with Anaconda, and I got the following -- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491268/install-pycairo-in-virtualenv
I tried installing cairo with 
    ' pip install cairocffi'
the installation had no errors, but I was unable to call 
   'import cairocffi' 
from python module

Other option I found was to install cairo with brew -- 
is the only option to install 'py2cairo' 
uninstall Anaconda python and install python with brew?

Comment: Probably the same issue; when you type `pip install cairocffi`, it installs `cairocffi` into one of your Python distributions, and then you try to import it from the other one. As for your last question: no, there are plenty of other ways; for instance, I compiled Python on my own using `pyenv` and then I compiled both `igraph` and `cairo` for this particular Python installation. You only have to make sure that when you invoke `pip install whatever`, then you call the "right" `pip`, i.e. the one that belongs to the Python distribution that you intend to use.

Comment: So, if Anaconda Python provides its own copy of `pip`, make sure to call that particular `pip` when you invoke `pip install cairocffi` and not the one that comes with OS X by default.

Comment: I will look into this and get back to you - thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try updating your PYTHONPATH variable, e.g. (insert your username in place of NNNN):

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/NNNN/anaconda/bin/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to install pycairo, py2cairo but igraph's plot would not work.

The following solved the igraph plotting issue:

```
sudo pip install cairocffi
```

Instead of pycairo I used cairocffi and this solved my problem.