# Build of py2cairo fails in Mac OS X with Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, igraph, cairo, pycairo

I've made the debatable decision to do some network analysis directly in Python instead of R. However, I'm having trouble getting all the `igraph` dependencies installed, ultimately failing with py2cairo.

After updating Xcode to latest, installed `cairo` with Homebrew:

```
brew install cairo
```

A few warnings there for dependent libraries, and the `brew link` step failed. After chowning a few directories, I ran `brew link` again and it worked.

Then, I uninstalled and re-installed `python-igraph` using `pip`.

Now I need to install py2cairo from source (I'm running Python 2.7.6 in a virtualenv) and so downloaded it from this source:

```
git clone git://git.cairographics.org/git/py2cairo
```

Following [Install pycairo in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491268/install-pycairo-in-virtualenv), I ran `./waf configure --prefix=$VIRTUAL_ENV` with no problems.

Running `./waf build` falls over with these errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.2_1/lib/libcairo.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.2_1/lib/libcairo.dylib
[...]
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I then tried to switch to using `autogen.sh`. First problem was that pkg.m4 was missing on my machine, so I tried reinstalling pkg-config with Homebrew again. Didn't work. So I downloaded pkg.m4 from here http://web.mit.edu/barnowl/src/pkg-config/pkg-config-0.23/pkg.m4, then installed `libtools` with Homebrew, and changed references in autogen to `glibtoolize` etc.

But then `autogen.sh` terminates with following errors:

```
autogen.sh: running `aclocal'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/m4:/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/aclocal/pkg.m4:155: ERROR: end of file in comment
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

Comment: You are probably running a Python built for the `i386` architecture in your `virtualenv`, but the version of Cairo that you have installed from Homebrew is for `x86_64`. Can you try it with a different version of Python that is built for `x86_64`?

Comment: When I run `platform.architecture()` I get `('64bit','') and sys.maxsize is 9223372036854775807. Might I still be running in 32bit mode somehow?

Comment: Probably not, but still the error message that `ld` printed after you ran `waf build` explicitly states that you are linking something for the `i386` architecture (i.e. 32-bit) while `libcairo.dylib` provides 64-bit architecture code only. It *could* be the case that `waf` is trying to build a "universal" library (containing 32-bit and 64-bit code as well). I would try `brew uninstall cairo && brew install cairo --universal` - this should build Cairo for 32-bit and 64-bit archs as well so you could then link to it from `waf build`.

Comment: System Python is a universal build, as Tamás alludes. Using a universal cairo, like he suggests, or a thin python (like Homebrew's) should help. You can also install py2cairo with brew and then create your virtualenv with --system-site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

`` export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64' # this is for Mac os x
./waf clean
./waf configure --prefix=`python -c "import sys; print sys.prefix"`
./waf build
./waf install ``

This works well on my Mac