# Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path REDHAT6.5

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run setup.py related to a proprietary software installation and it has dependencies on libffi.

Since its Redhat 6.5 the python version was 2.6 and i installed python 2.7.

libffi was already installed and when i create a virtualenv and try installing the software by running the setup.py i get the following error:

```
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:63:

yum list libffi
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Installed Packages
libffi.x86_64                  3.0.5-3.2.el6                   @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201311111358.x86_64/6.5
Available Packages
libffi.i686                    3.0.5-3.2.el6                   rhel-local
```

My query is how do we modify the pkg-config search path.
to point to libffi.pc?

Comment: You need the `libffi-dev` package

Comment: Hi, I already have the package installed inspite of which i am getting this error. Please refer to the above output "yum list libffi"

Comment: That output is for `libffi`, not `libffi-dev`.

Comment: @jordanm - Thanks a lot it really helped. You are right i downloaded the rpm pkg for libffi-dev "libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64.rpm" and installed and it worked. I was under the impression that libffi and libffi-dev are same. But its not. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Aprameya NDS. Actually yum can inform : `yum provides */ffi.h`  ,  `yum provides */libffi.pc` ... or use the online search http://rpm.pbone.net/ ... and have a look at the package list http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Thanks Knud Larsen

Answer (score 39):

try after installing:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi6 libffi-dev
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I have a docker build that has never failed... today it fails with this error so I added libffi-dev and the build works again.  It would be nice to know WHAT changed, but hey... it's working again, right?

Comment: same comment as @frozenjim.

Works after adding `libffi libffi-dev`.

Note that `libffi6` could have been outdated now

Comment: for alpine-linux worked for me just 
`apk add libffi-dev`

Comment: I had an issue with GCC and one of the lines in errors was saying `No package 'libffi' found`. I have added `libffi-dev` and it started working. thanks

Comment: Worked for me only with: 
`sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`

Answer (score 22):

You will need the development version of libffi to install libraries which depends on libffi :

```
sudo yum install libffi-devel
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue for MacOS. I assume the solution should be similar.

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add these two lines below to the end of your bash_profile so that it can be discovered

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
```

Save and quit and restart Terminal

Comment: can you share your stack trace and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Commenting to simply point out that it does work for some users (for me it did).

Answer (score 5):

Faced a similar issue while installing paramiko using pip3:

$ pip3 install paramiko

ERROR:

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found

No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.

distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

RESOLUTION:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$ pip3 install paramiko
```

Successfully installed asn1crypto bcrypt cffi cryptography-1.2.3 paramiko-1.16.0 pycparser pynacl six-1.10.0

Comment: trying to install audio-to-midi, this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error from docker build. So I added just below command in my Dockerfile and solved my issue.

PS: my base image is alpine-linux

```
RUN apk update \
&& apk --no-cache --update add libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using python 3.8 and getting the same error while wheel was trying to setup cffi on a conda environment. I tried installing libffi and libffi-dev (and exiting the terminal and reactivating the environment each time was installing something!) but with no luck. I then thought that maybe downgrading python to 3.7 might solve the issue. I did that in my conda environment (just activated the environment and ran conda install python=3.7 and then all of the sudden libffi was found! wheel was able to setup cffi and all were working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

try this

> `sudo apt-get install -y python3-cffi`