# Failed building wheel for pycairo using manim in Python 3.7 environment

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo, manim

I am following the steps outlined [here](https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2018/06/11/installing-manim-and-python-manim-series-part-1/) to set up maths animation for educational purposes. I've had to figure out how to configure all the steps for Python 3.7, but that hasn't posed any major problems. However, I'm now running into errors I can't quite understand, which seems to come from the pycairo package (I've highlighted the errors in bold below). I tried following the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131876/pycairo-installation-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) to fix the errors, but although I have successfully installed the latest pycairo package (1.17), I continue to get the same errors. I've got some programming experience but I'm brand new to python so I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've posted the code below (bolded the errors):

```
(manim37) C:\Users\a1689869\Anaconda3\manim>pip install -r requirements.txt

Requirement already satisfied: argparse==1.4.0 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colour==0.1.5 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.15.0 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow==5.2.0 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: progressbar==2.5 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.1.0 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm==4.24.0 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (4.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python==3.4.2.17 in c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (3.4.2.17)
Collecting pycairo==1.17.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/76/340ff847897296b2c8174dfa5a5ec3406e3ed783a2abac918cf326abad86/pycairo-1.17.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
  **Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycairo ... error**
  Complete output from command c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\a1689869\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cicoey3g\\pycairo\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\a1689869\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-29uyasfz --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
  running build_ext
  building 'cairo._cairo' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=17 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -Ic:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\include -Ic:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
  device.c
  **c:\users\a1689869\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-cicoey3g\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory**
  **error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2**

  ----------------------------------------
  **Failed building wheel for pycairo
  Running setup.py clean for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
Installing collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error**
    Complete output from command c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\a1689869\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cicoey3g\\pycairo\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\a1689869\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ld4ke0sg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\cairo
    running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=17 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=1 -Ic:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\include -Ic:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
    device.c
    **c:\users\a1689869\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-cicoey3g\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.13.26128\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\a1689869\anaconda3\envs\manim37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\a1689869\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cicoey3g\\pycairo\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\a1689869\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ld4ke0sg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\a1689869\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cicoey3g\pycairo\
```

Comment: This is a known issue: [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/292), [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/524) and [here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/751). I solved this issue myself with `brew install pkg-config` but that was on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

it appears that you are using anaconda. From what i see, there seems to be some issues when building the wheel for pycairo. Probably you could try installing pycairo manually and then reinstalling manimlib again in the anaconda prompt.

`conda install -c conda-forge pycairo`

[source - conda-forge/pycairo](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycairo)

Answer (score 2):

I have got problem with pycairo. And I have done solved by the step.

You need to sure dependencies of correct version.

To downgrade them, first uninstall:

```
pip uninstall Pillow idna requests urllib3
```

Then you should  install with specific versions:

```
pip install Pillow==5.3.0 idna==2.6 requests==2.18.4 urllib3==1.22
```